# Migrating project from linux to windows - Error parsing XML: not well-formed - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding

I was developing an Android project in linux. The project runs fine. But when I clone the same project in windows my android studio give below error for few strings xml file.

```
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed
```

but the same project works well in linux. Getting the issue only when running the project in windows

I tried changing the File Encoding in settings to UTF-8 still it dint work. Any other solution to fix this ?

Comment: do add the error code that you got in your strings xml file or share your xml file here.

Comment: your question is limited to debug, try to use online xml [validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)

Comment: what do u mean by its limited to "debug"

Comment: do add your xml file. so it will be easy to debug / find parsing error.

Comment: @JosePraveen thanks for your time. I have found the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem.
The issue was that Linux was creating the file in UTF-8 format and the same file was being read by windows in its default format i.e windows-1252 (this is for java8)

So we need to set the Java Tool Options to use UTF-8. To do this add below line in your gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

This is important "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

I found this in one of SO post, cant find it now. Once I find it will link it.